# Science Fiction short story where men have to kill each other to settle some sort of conflict

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember a science fiction short story where men have to kill each other to settle some sort of conflict. They are on a small planet or asteroid with low gravity and no oxygen and are wearing space suits. The main character dies and the person who ends up being victorious, kills time by jumping from one dead body to the next while waiting for someone to pick him up.

The story might be "And Then There Was One" by Ross Rocklynne. ..I am trying to find the text to verify. . . .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it

> **"And Then There Was One" by Ross Rocklynne.**

The way I found it was interesting. After I posted my question, I started looking through other questions to see if I could help out.  I came across a question about two men who get stuck on a frictionless mirror surface.  I thought, *"Wow, that sounds like one of the stories in the anthology that my story came from."*  So I looked at the answer and it said the story was "The Men on the Mirror" by Ross Rocklynne and was from an anthology of the same name.  I looked up that anthology on ISFDB and found "And Then There was One" then I had only to find a summary of ATTWO (I actually ordered the book from Amazon as well), and voila! Story found!  So this website helped me find the story in an unexpected way!